# Updating the table through tOracleOutput in Talend using an additional SQL query

Tags: talend

I have a job where I am getting a flow into tOracleOutput where I am updating the table. Now, I have to update that table using an SQL statement, which I guess we have option in Advanced settings of tOracleOuptut, but I don't know how to use it or you can say that I am not getting the settings properly. I referred to official documentation but could not understand. Can any one explain the fields like Name, SQL expression, Position, Reference Column in a better way?

the SQL query which I am using is:

**update  set COL1=SOMETHING1
where COL2=SOMETHING2**

Now, value for COL1 is coming from the flow but COL2 is some column in the table which is not coming from the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to tOracleRow for such a case.
Hope this helps.

TRF

Answer (score 0):

Using tOracleOutput is helpful when a ready data source (table or file (...) with same columns as destination) the more elaborate your query is, the more you should do as TRF said (and use tOracleRow), but here's an example to your question:

- file contain 3 column,
- DB table of destination contains 4 column, where the 4th is the date of update, (the first 3 are identical to the input)

so you add the destination's column's name in **Name** and put the **SQL function** for the date (eg: SYSDATE) and where to put it (**Position**) in reference to a column of your choice (**Reference Column**)

In my view it helps avoid using tMap for a miserable additional column when you want to Insert, but you want to Update, in which case the component doesn't offer the additional column section,  plus I don't think you can add the WHERE clause here

Hope it helps